# How to pass single quote text as parameter to stored procedure in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to pass "Ram's" or "I'm xxx" type of single quote data as parameter to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the stored proc like this

```
exec stored_proc_name @param_name='Ram''s'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quote by another quote

```
'Ram''s'
```